# How to check if a program is installed and install it if it is not?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, installation, powershell-4.0

I would rather not use WMI due the integrity check.

This is what I have that does not work:

```
$tempdir = Get-Location
$tempdir = $tempdir.tostring()

$reg32 = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
$reg64 = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

if((Get-ItemProperty $reg32 | Select-Object DisplayName | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Like '*Microsoft Interop Forms*' } -eq $null) -Or (Get-ItemProperty $reg64 | Select-Object DisplayName | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Like '*Microsoft Interop Forms*' } -eq $null))
        {
        (Start-Process -FilePath $tempdir"\microsoft.interopformsredist.msi" -ArgumentList "-qb" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
        }
```

It always returns false. If I switch it to `-ne $null` it always returns true so I know it is detecting `$null` output even though, I believe (but could be wrong), the `Get-ItemProperty` is returning a result that should be counting as something other than `$null`.

Comment: Have you looked at Chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/? Packages are easy to make and all the hard work is done for you.

Answer (score 34):

```
$tempdir = Get-Location
$tempdir = $tempdir.tostring()
$appToMatch = '*Microsoft Interop Forms*'
$msiFile = $tempdir+"\microsoft.interopformsredist.msi"
$msiArgs = "-qb"

function Get-InstalledApps
{
    if ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
        $regpath = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    }
    else {
        $regpath = @(
            'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        )
    }
    Get-ItemProperty $regpath | .{process{if($_.DisplayName -and $_.UninstallString) { $_ } }} | Select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate, DisplayVersion, UninstallString |Sort DisplayName
}

$result = Get-InstalledApps | where {$_.DisplayName -like $appToMatch}

If ($result -eq $null) {
    (Start-Process -FilePath $msiFile -ArgumentList $msiArgs -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Can you then please mark it as the answer?(it's the tick under the down arrow).

Comment: I found this very useful, would you mind explaining what the code:

If ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) 

is checking for?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi,

I also have a question. Mind explaining the'' $msiArgs -Wait -Passthru'' part please? Thanks!

Comment: @Bajan it's a method to determine the OS architecture.  The value of the [IntPtr] property is 4 in a 32-bit process, and 8 in a 64-bit process.

Comment: @ChrisVermeijlen; $msiArgs is just a variable to store the arguments you want to pass onto the MSI, in the example above we are just passing "-qb".  You could store any other MSI argument like, "/norestart ALLUSERS=2" etc.

The "-wait -Passthru" are parameters for the Start-Process cmdlet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: One question: why the -Passthru on the Start-Process when there's nothing to passthru to? If you are not piping the result to anything what is -Passthru for?

Comment: @Tom Padilla - Yes, if the script is on its own, you don't need it, but the OP had it in their original code to pipe out the ExitCode.

Answer (score -2):

## Example for `az` command line tool

```
try {
    az --version
    echo "az is installed"
} catch {
    echo "az isn't installed"
}
```