# Powershell script to install software

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a powershell script that I can use with an RMM tool. So, basically this powershell script would be executed on the local machine. It would need to check to see if the version of the application is installed and at least version number xx. If not installed, or version is less, it would then download executable and silently install it.

I found an example online for Adobe Reader that does work, but it doesn't do the check before hand. So, this script would install Adobe Reader every time it is ran.

```
$tempFolder=$Env:TEMP

function runProcess ($cmd, $params) {
$p = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$exitcode = $false
$p.StartInfo.FileName = $cmd
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = $params
$p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $False
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $True
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $True
$p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = 1;
$null = $p.Start()
$p.WaitForExit()
$output = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$exitcode = $p.ExitCode
$p.Dispose()
$exitcode
$output
}

#download installer
invoke-webrequest "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/1500720033/AcroRdrDC1500720033_en_US.msi" -OutFile "$tempFolder\AcroRdrDC1500720033_en_US.msi" -ErrorAction Stop

#run installer
$res = runProcess msiexec "/i $tempFolder\AcroRdrDC1500720033_en_US.msi /qb"

#check if return code is 0
if(0 -ne $res[0]){
return "Failed to install Adobe Reader: $($res[0]) $($res[1])"
}

#download the patch
invoke-webrequest "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/1502320070/AcroRdrDCUpd1502320070.msp" -OutFile "$tempFolder\AcroRdrDCUpd1502320070.msp" -ErrorAction Stop

#install it
$res = runProcess msiexec "/p $tempFolder\AcroRdrDCUpd1502320070.msp /qb"

#check if return code is 0
if(0 -ne $res[0]){
return "Failed to install Adobe Reader DC Patch: $($res[0]) $($res[1])"
}else{
#Attempt to silently disable the auto updater if set in this script
new-itemproperty "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown" -name bUpdater -value 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I think there are some things that may not be needed in this script. It also doesn't have the check for version.

Found this on another site, but not sure how to implement it. Also, it doesn't look like it checks for version number.

```
function Is-Installed( $program ) {

    $x86 = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
        Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$program*" } ).Length -gt 0;

    $x64 = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
        Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$program*" } ).Length -gt 0;

    return $x86 -or $x64;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to set the parameters at the top so I could use a template for other executables. For instance

```
$app_name
$app_version
$app_url
$app_filename
$app_executable
$app_arguments
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any help with what? Designing a turnkey solution for you? (That's not the purpose of this site.)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and found this post: [How to check if a program is installed and install it if it is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712686/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-and-install-it-if-it-is-not)

Which allows for matching Name and Version:

```
$tempdir = Get-Location
$tempdir = $tempdir.tostring()
$appName = '*AirParrot*'
$appVersion = "2.6.8"
$msiFile = $tempdir+"\microsoft.interopformsredist.msi"
$msiArgs = "-qb"

function Get-InstalledApps
{
    if ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
        $regpath = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    }
    else {
        $regpath = @(
            'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        )
    }
    Get-ItemProperty $regpath | .{process{if($_.DisplayName -and $_.UninstallString) { $_ } }} | Select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate, DisplayVersion, UninstallString |Sort DisplayName

}

$result = Get-InstalledApps | where {$_.DisplayName -like $appName -and $_.DisplayVersion -ge $appVersion}

If ($result -eq $null) {
    (Start-Process -FilePath $msiFile -ArgumentList $msiArgs -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
}
```

Comment: I just realized that mine doesn't compare the version.